# Como utilizar cache no NHibernate com C#

Tags: c#, cache, nhibernate

Galera, como eu posso utilizar cache no NHibernate com C#? Qual é a melhor forma de implementação? E quais são as considerações que devo levar?

Comment: Cara, vai ficar enorme responder isso. Melhor começar [por este artigo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/529016/NHibernate-Second-Level-Caching-Implementation) e fazer outras perguntas mais específicas.

Comment: Legal! Esses comentários são importantes. Porque a gente(que questiona) não sabe mensurar o tamanho ou a complexidade da resposta. Não ligo em suspender perguntas, mas não admito comentários críticos não construtivos. Obrigado pelo comentário SUPER construtivo @Cigano. Parabéns pelo seu trabalho aqui na stackoverflow!